# Connecting IBOutlet Xcode 4.4

Tags: ios, xcode4.4

I just finished upgrading to Xcode 4.4 because the previous version of Xcode would not let me develop/test applications for iOS>5.0

Anyhow, I started creating an application - a tab bar controller application. Inside the first view, I created a button (an IBOutlet) but now it seems that I am unable to make the connection between the scene and the view controller in the storyboard.

When I control-Click the view controller in the storyboard, under outlets I can only see searchDisplayViewController and View. I can't see the outlets I just created.

Thanks

**EDIT** - If the view is not connected to a scene in the tab bar item, it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried ctrl dragging from the button to the View Controller? Try also ctrl dragging from the button to the header file of the view controller.

Another possible solution would be to select the button, open the last tab of the right pannel and look for the connection there.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself: InterfaceBuilder appears to be now particular about where the IBOutlets are placed, so you want them NOT in the .h of your class as it used to be, but in your .m. If it's the other way around, IB won't display the outlets to connect.

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *caption;
@end

@implementation MyViewController
@synthesize scrollview, photo, caption;
...
@end
```